# Updating matching line with sed/grep

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I need to replace pattern matching line with yet another string.

Example

```
line1
line2
the serial port is ttyS0
line4
```

I need to replace line containing `ttyS0` as

```
line1
line2
You have to use usb interface
line4
```

How can I do that in sed (or grep)

I tried `sed 's/ttyS0/You have to use usb interface/' myfile` . But it replaces only the matching words from the line. I want to replace the complete line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed 's/.*ttyS0.*/You have to use usb interface/' myfile
```

Answer (score 3):

One way using the [change](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-42) option:

```
sed '/ttyS0/c\You have to use usb interface' myfile
```